# Parent process clean up thread that raised exception

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-multithreading

I have some code that contains two objects something to this effect:

```
class Parent(object): 
    def __init__(): 
        self.child = None

    def stuffParentDoes(): 
        while True: 
            if self.child is None: 
                self.child = Child(randint(1,1000))
                self.child.start()
            else:
                print self.child

            time.sleep(3)

class Child(Thread): 
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def run(): 
        print "%s child doing child stuff" % self.name
        time.sleep(3)


parent = Parent()        
parent.stuffParentDoes()
```

**My problem is this.**  If `Child` is spawned and running properly, the `print Child` will give something like this  `<Child(Thread-2, started 140038530209536)>`.  If it raises an exception, it'll print something like this  `<Child(Thread-2, stopped 140038530209536)>`

My `Parent` object need to know that its stopped, clean up it's own `self.child` variable, then restart another `Child` in its place.  Obviously this is over simplified but hopefully you get my point.  Calling `join()` on the child doesn't work either because `Parent` has many other things to do and since `join()` is blocking that causes a problem.

**EDIT:** 
What ended up solving my problem was moving my reference to the child thread outside the scope of my parent object.  When the reference was in the global scope, I didn't have a problem unsetting it when I needed to restart the child.

Comment: There are two ways: either parent waits until child terminates or raising a volatile flag. The parent have to poll that flag periodically. Third method is that parent is a service. It has a message que and operates by consuming and executing the message-specified commands.

Comment: `join()` can be nonblocking, give it a timeout like `join(0.)`

Comment: @shavenwarthog what would it do after it executes its timeout if the child hasn't thrown an exception yet and is still running?  the python docs are a little confusing to me there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code maintains a 'pool' of threads (aka children).  Every second, dead threads are removed, and new ones added to maintain 3 threads at all times.

For a larger projects consider going to the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module, specifically the `ThreadPoolExecutor` function.  I also recommend 3rd party library `gevent` (flexible, fast, Python2 only) and internal module `multiprocessing` (has Pool, is included in all Pythons).

## source

```
import threading, time
from random import random

class Child(threading.Thread): 
    def run(self): 
        print "\t%s: child doing child stuff" % self
        # sleep 1-3 seconds
        time.sleep( 1. + random()*2 )


nchildren = 3
tpool = []

for _ in range(4):
    diff = nchildren - len(tpool)
    if diff < 1:
        print '* okay'
    else:
        print '* starting {} children'.format(diff)
        new_children = [ Child() for _ in xrange(diff) ]
        for thread in new_children:
            thread.start()
        tpool.extend( new_children )

    time.sleep(1)
    print '* scan...', 
    tpool = [ thread for thread in tpool
              if thread.isAlive()
              ]
    print '{} children'.format(len(tpool))
```

### output

```
* starting 3 children
    <Child(Thread-1, started 47211446597376)>: child doing child stuff
    <Child(Thread-2, started 47211448698624)>: child doing child stuff
    <Child(Thread-3, started 47211450799872)>: child doing child stuff
* scan... 3 children
* okay
* scan... 2 children
* starting 1 children
    <Child(Thread-4, started 47211448698624)>: child doing child stuff
* scan... 1 children
* starting 2 children
    <Child(Thread-5, started 47211450799872)>: child doing child stuff
    <Child(Thread-6, started 47211446597376)>: child doing child stuff
* scan... 3 children
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This didn't solve my problem but it lead to the solution.  When I moved my reference to the children threads outside the parent object, all worked as I expected.